# KeyError at /api/social/convert-token

Tags: python, django-socialauth

I am building an app that lets customers and drivers sign in via Facebook. While testing using postman, I was able to create access tokens. However, when I then went to create an access token that differentiates whether a user is a customer or a driver, I get this error in postman. "KeyError at /api/social/convert-token
'user_type'"

I have passed all the necessary params (i.e client_id, client_secret, user_type, grant_type, backend, and FB token), so it isn't a param problem.

My settings.py is:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'foodtaskerapp.social_auth_pipeline.create_user_by_type',  # <--- set the path to the function
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

and my social_auth_pipeline.py looks like this

```
from foodtaskerapp.models import Customer, Driver

def create_user_by_type(backend, user, request, response, *args, **kwargs):
    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        avatar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' % response['id']

    if request['user_type'] == "driver" and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        Driver.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar = avatar)
    elif not Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
        Customer.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar = avatar)
```

Both models have been set up as well in models.py.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='customer')
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()

class Driver(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='driver')
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Why am I getting the error?

Comment: `request.POST.get('user_type')`?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @KlausD. I tried that and got the error "'dict' object has no attribute 'POST'." I found when I added "request['user_type'] = ['driver', 'customer']" above the if/elif statement I got rid of the user_type error, but the only problem was that if I passed the param as driver or customer, it only saves in Django as a customer no matter what

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Edit **create_user_by_type()** method to fix this issue:

```
def create_user_by_type(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
request = backend.strategy.request_data()
if backend.name == 'facebook':
    avatar = 'https://graph.facebook.com/%s/picture?type=large' % response['id']

if request["user_type"] == "driver" and not Driver.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
    Driver.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar = avatar)
elif not Customer.objects.filter(user_id=user.id):
    Customer.objects.create(user_id=user.id, avatar = avatar)
```